# Tezos removed by baker

Tags: baking

i had some tezos removed by my baker (fresh tezos). Would this just be their annual fee? i always assumed they took their 15% before distributing xtz to my account. Why would they removed a large sum in one lump?

regards

Comment: Tezos delegation is non-custodial. This means when you delegate to a baker you always keep custody of your tokens. The baker can only decide how much reward to pay you for the delegation, they can not deduct any of your balance ever. Make sure that you did not accidentally send your tokens to the baker rather than delegate to them, if you did this you need to contact them to get them back. This question is closed as it should be asked on Tezos Telegram, Riot, or Reddit.

Answer (score 2):

Your Baker cannot take your XTZ.